# How to arrange Flex component to scroll properly

Tags: apache-flex, layout

In following code, I have one large component, and I'd like only the level4 panel to be scrollable, but instead, the whole application become scrollable.

Any suggestion ? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application  xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
<mx:Panel width="100%" height="100%" title="level1">
    <mx:Panel width="100%" height="100%" title="level2">
        <mx:HDividedBox width="100%" height="100%">

            <mx:TextArea width="200" height="100%"/>
            <mx:Panel width="100%" height="100%" title="level3">
                <mx:ApplicationControlBar width="100%" dock="true">
                    <mx:Spacer width="30"/>
                    <mx:LegendItem  width="80" height="20" fill="#CC9900" label="test1"/>

                </mx:ApplicationControlBar>
                <mx:Panel width="100%" height="100%" title="level4">
                    <mx:UIComponent width="2000" height="2000"/>
                </mx:Panel>
            </mx:Panel>
        </mx:HDividedBox>
    </mx:Panel>
</mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

If I set ScrollPolicy, then no scrollbar will be shown up. Please check the following, thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application  xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
<mx:Panel width="100%" height="100%" title="level1" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
    <mx:Panel width="100%" height="100%" title="level2" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
        <mx:HDividedBox width="100%" height="100%">

            <mx:TextArea width="200" height="100%"/>
            <mx:Panel width="100%" height="100%" title="level3" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
                <mx:ApplicationControlBar width="100%" dock="true">
                    <mx:Spacer width="30"/>
                    <mx:LegendItem  width="80" height="20" fill="#CC9900" label="test1"/>

                </mx:ApplicationControlBar>
                <mx:Panel width="100%" height="100%" title="level4" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"  verticalScrollPolicy="auto">
                    <mx:UIComponent width="2000" height="2000"/>
                </mx:Panel>
            </mx:Panel>
        </mx:HDividedBox>
    </mx:Panel>
</mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set layout="absolute" for the level4 panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of `.verticalScrollBarPolicy` for each Panel, setting it to `"off"` for the Panels that should not scroll, and to `"on"` or `"auto"` for the Panels that should scroll. There is also a `.horizontalScrollBarPolicy` parameter if you need that as well.

Comment: Then all the scrollbar disappeared, although I set the most inner panel to use scrollbar. Please check my updated code.

Comment: @BlueDolphin Hmm. When I have a minute, I'll come back and try to address this.